# How to update value based on other input box dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a shopping cart.

Where I have list of products which has different price.

Now when i tried to change the quantity the price should change based on quantity as well as the total one.

But the problem i'm facing is using the below code when i tried to change the quantity, price get updated but the others also get updated as well though i didn't change the Quantity.

Then total one doesn't show the appropriate total

```js
$(".quantity").change(update);

function update() {
  $(".quantity").each(function() {
    var qty = Number($(this).val());
    var net = document.getElementById("net_price").value;
    var total = qty * net;
    $('.total').html("$" + total);
    $(".grandTotal").text(calculateSum());
  });

  function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".total").each(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(value);
      }
    });
    return sum;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="qty table-default">
  <input type="number" class="quantity" value="" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" /></td>
<td class="total_price table-default total"></td>
<td><input type="hidden" id="net_price" value="">45</td>
<td class="grandTotal"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Anyone please help me to find the soultion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly this may help you

```js
$('body').on('change', ".quantity", update);

function update() {

  var qty = parseInt($(this).val());
  var net = parseFloat($(this).parents('tr').find(".net_price").val());
  var total = qty * net;
  $(this).parents('tr').find(".total_price").text("$" + total);
  $(".grandTotal").text('$' + calculateSum());

  function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".total_price").each(function() {
      var value = $(this).text().replace('$', '');
      if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(value);
      }
    });
    return sum;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="qty table-default">
      <td><input type="text" readonly class="net_price" value="25"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="quantity" value="" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" /></td>
      <td class="total_price table-default total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="qty table-default">
      <td><input type="text" readonly class="net_price" value="25"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="quantity" value="" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" /></td>
      <td class="total_price table-default total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="qty table-default">
      <td><input type="text" readonly class="net_price" value="25"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="quantity" value="" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" /></td>
      <td class="total_price table-default total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colsapn="3" class="grandTotal"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Performance Improvement**
A performance improvement of above code by extracting calculateSum externally to avoid recreation of same function again and again while calling update method

```js
$('body').on('change', ".quantity", update);

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".total_price").each(function() {
      var value = $(this).text().replace('$', '');
      if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(value);
      }
    });
    return sum;
}
function update() {
  var qty = parseInt($(this).val());
  var net = parseFloat($(this).parents('tr').find(".net_price").val());
  var total = qty * net;
  $(this).parents('tr').find(".total_price").text("$" + total);
  $(".grandTotal").text('$' + calculateSum());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="qty table-default">
      <td><input type="text" readonly class="net_price" value="25"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="quantity" value="" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" /></td>
      <td class="total_price table-default total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="qty table-default">
      <td><input type="text" readonly class="net_price" value="25"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="quantity" value="" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" /></td>
      <td class="total_price table-default total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="qty table-default">
      <td><input type="text" readonly class="net_price" value="25"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="quantity" value="" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" /></td>
      <td class="total_price table-default total"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colsapn="3" class="grandTotal"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Every time you're calling the update function, it's re-creating the `calculateSum` function

Comment: @vol7ron i just findout his bugs not done any performance improvements

Answer (score 0):

- You are setting the `HTML` value for element which is `$` concatenated with value but while retrieving the value, you are using `.val()` method. To get the `text` from the element, use `.text` method instead.
- As value is prefixed with `$`, we can not use it for manipulations hence `.data` method is used to store numerical value in `data` for particular element.
- `jQuery.data('key')` is used to retrieve the value.

```js
$(".quantity").change(update);

function update() {
  $(".quantity").each(function() {
    var qty = Number($(this).val());
    var net = 10; //Static value is considered
    var total = qty * net;
    var totalElem = $('.total');
    totalElem.html("$" + total);
    totalElem.data("value", total);
    $(".grandTotal").text(calculateSum());
  });

  function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".total").each(function() {
      var value = $(this).data('value');
      if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(value);
      }
    });
    return sum;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="qty table-default">
      <input type="number" class="quantity" value="" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" />
    </td>
    <td class="total_price table-default total"></td>
    <td class="grandTotal"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: GrandTotal showing Correctly But the problem is suppose i have two products on cart..when i change the quantity of second one first one price also get updated.and I can't update the price of first one..
thanks

Comment: Does provided code in answer work ? Please provide "suppose" scenario in your question..

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".quantity").change(update);

function update() {
  // Cell Variables
  var $qty = $(this),
    $row = $qty.closest('tr'),
    $total = $row.find('.total');

  // Number Variables
  var qty = Number($qty.val()),
    price = $row.find('.price').val(),
    total = qty * price;

  // Fill Values
  $total.html("$" + total);
  $('.grandTotal').text('$' + calculateSum());
}

function calculateSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.total').each(function() {
    var strTotal = $(this).text();
    var total = parseFloat(strTotal.replace(/^\D+/g, ''));

    if (!isNaN(total))
      sum += total;
  });
  return sum;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Grand Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="qty table-default">
        <input type="number" class="quantity" value="" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" />
      </td>
      <td><input type="hidden" class="price" value="45" />$45</td>
      <td class="total_price table-default total"></td>
      <td class="grandTotal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="qty table-default">
        <input type="number" class="quantity" value="" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" />
      </td>
      <td><input type="hidden" class="price" value="10" />$10</td>
      <td class="total_price table-default total"></td>
      <td class="grandTotal"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @hola I suppose this is what you're after, it could be made much more efficient, but should be used as a stepping point from where you're at to where you want to be